# Multiple queries in WHERE clause

Tags: php, sql, select, get, where-clause

Struggling with this one.. my sql query works in PHP myAdmin but not on the page..

The url: 
    http://www.copleycaravanservices.co.uk/Caravans.php?room_id=1&foreign_id=1
    There is also another query which works for the room_id section of the url

The code that isnt working:

```
<?php
require_once('db_config.php');
mysql_select_db($dbname, $db);
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM  `SS_hotel_booking_multi_lang` 
WHERE  `foreign_id` = " . $_GET['foreign_id'] . "
AND  `locale` = '1'
AND  `field` =  'description'
AND  `source` =  'data'";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1, $db) or die(mysql_error());
$CaravanDesc = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1);
?>
```

The database: (Hope this displays correctly!)

```
id  foreign_id  model   locale  field   content              source
7365    1       pjRoom    1     name    Promenade 654          data
7366    1       pjRoom    1  description This caravan sleeps 6 data
7371    2       pjRoom    1     name    Butlins Sandhills 14   data
7372    2       pjRoom    1  description 4 Day Passes included data
```

Comment: Use single quotes around your string values: `$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM  \`SS_hotel_booking_multi_lang\` 
WHERE (\`foreign_id\` = " . $_GET['foreign_id'] . "
AND  \`locale\` = "1"
AND  \`field\` =  'description'
AND \`model\` =  'pjRoom')";`

Comment: Then consider the risk of SQL injection for `$_GET['foreign_id']`

Comment: Then start learning to use MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements/bind variables, rather than the old, deprecated MySQL interface

Comment: The `or die(mysql_error())` should have thrown you syntax errors. Learn to interpret them and correct them accordingly. @MarkBaker told you what to use. Edit: Correction, it did `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'model` = 'pjRoom' AND `locale` = '1' AND `source` = 'data')' at line 2`

Comment: Im using 123-reg as a host and using their standard MySQL interface.

Comment: Thanks mark and fred, the error i get is 
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'model` = 'pjRoom' AND `locale` = '1' AND `source` = 'data')' at line 2

Comment: Your edit doesn't support the error you're getting: use near 'model` = having a quote and a tick. Update your question and code to reflect this. You can try removing the `()` around your `where` clause.

Comment: Im really a newbie at all this, im not sure what it means exactly.. What should i do exactly?

Comment: `WHERE (` <= remove that `(` and `=  'data')";` remove that `)`. Update your question with the actual column names and add the error you are getting.

Comment: `$_GET['foreign_id']` what is going through for that?

Comment: It should be the foreign_id in the url, so all items in the database where foreign_id=1 for example are pulled up. so in this query i should have two results (rows where ID: 7365 and 7366)

Comment: `room_id` in your URL `?room_id=1` where is that assigned in your GET? I also reopened the question. Plus, what are your column types?

Comment: the room_id is in another query, it pulls the room_id (resulting in the room name being displayed) from another table all together.

Comment: <?php
require_once('db_config.php');
mysql_select_db($dbname, $db);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `SS_hotel_booking_discount_packages` WHERE room_id = " . $_GET['room_id'] . "";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $db) or die(mysql_error());
$CaravansName = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should be done like this try by removing quotes of column name

```
 <?php
    require_once('db_config.php');
    mysql_select_db($dbname, $db);
    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM  `SS_hotel_booking_multi_lang` 
    WHERE  foreign_id = " . $_GET['foreign_id'] . "
    AND  locale = '1'
    AND  field =  'description'
    AND  source =  'data'";
    $result1 = mysql_query($sql1, $db) or die(mysql_error());
    $CaravanDesc = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1);
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks alot! It annoys me the solution is so simple!